# JNI Performance

Tags: java-native-interface, hdf5

Our main program is in java but the code that extracts our data from storage is written in C. I need to build an HDF5 file from extracted data. Would it be better to use JNI to call the C code to get the data and then build the HDF5 file from Java or to build the HDF5 from the C code?

I have little experience with JNI or C.

Also One of our main criteria is performance. How much of a performance hit is there when using JNI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function call boundary is "slow", so if you're doing many calls to your native routine, then performance will suffer.

An example of the kind of thing that **may** benefit from moving to JNI (I emphasize **may**, because Java is more than fast enough for many purposes) would be a routine to do some sort of image processing on a large bitmap. But to call a JNI routine for each *pixel* would be much, much slower than doing it within a loop in pure Java.

Extracting data from one format to another is, frankly, the kind of thing best done in a "scripting" language like Python, and will never be bound by CPU. Rather, the disk speed is going to be way, way slower than any language interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that since you have little experience with C, your best choice is to do it from withing Java.. JNI is really not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar at all with the HDF interfaces other than the C one, so I cannot really compare for you.

I would point out that this is the API which all other interfaces use, so if you're finding that you need to eek out the maximum performance then the C API is going to be the best.

There is also a question about what parts of the API are available to you.  For example I originally started with the C++ interface.  Some APIs were still only available in the C API.  This is not a problem when you're using C & C++ but it may be a problem if an API you need is not available to you.

Having said that, you do need to have your head screwed on in terms of the object model of C: eg. use of pointers, handles etc.